# Преобразование регулярного выражения в маску для input type = text

Tags: javascript

Пишу свой плагин "маска" на javascript + jquery. Справился с опцией "пользователь устанавливает маску например 000-00-00" - значит вместо 0 в input на этом месте может быть только цифра. Так же справился с моментом "пользователь устанавливает регулярное выражение" и по нему анализируется значение input на предмет поиска невалидных символов. Теперь вот задумался: возможно ли каким то образом конвертировать регулярное выражение, например `\d{1,3}` в значение input value="___" (три нижних подчеркивания, заменяющихся при вводе с клавиатуры на валидный для данной позиции в input символ)? Данный пример конечно простой, его можно просчитать, а вот к примеру регулярное выражение, позволяющее вводить валидный e-mail - уже сложновато. Есть ли такие способы или я заморачиваюсь нереализуемым?

Comment: Вы хотите странного. Регулярки сложны и далеко не все их них можно выразить маской. Даже в вашем примере вы уже придумали какой-то хак (почему три подчёркивания, а не одно?)

Comment: потому что по смыслу регулярного выражения "цифры от одной до трех" - вот поэтому три _

Comment: На мой взгяд вы усложняете. Удобнее использовать в плагине два параметра - маску и само регулярное выражение.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду под двумя параметрами в этом контексте. регулярка - это регулярка, а маска... как она выглядит относительно моей регулярки? но вы правы, я повертел и так и эдак - слишком как то все громоздко выходит